# Wildfly always sending content-type html

Tags: wildfly, mime-types, undertow

I'm migrating an app from jboss as 6 to wildfly 9.0.2.

The app is deploying and working, but I noticed something strange.

We have a login page in `webapp/login/login.jsp`, and it's assets are in `webapp/login/` too. Those assets are always transferred with the `Content-Type` header set to `text/html`.

I tried to remove all filters (including struts, for example), but still the content-type is wrong.

I tried to declare the mime-type mapping in web.xml for `css` and `js` files, also didn't work.

I even tried to set up a filter to override the content-type, and too didn't work.

I'm out of options here, does anyone ever seen anything like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error.

We have an internal framework (yeah, I know), developed by a former architect, and the framework was declaring a `@WebFilter("/*")` and changing all requests' content-types.

I guess Jboss AS mime-type filter were running after that crappy stuff, and fixing it's mistakes, and undertow's filter is probably running earlier, causing the broken requests.

Either way, I fixed that thing and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

you should rewrite content-type in frontend web server (such as apache) or add these mime-mapping configuration in web.xml of application:

```
<mime-mapping>
     <extension>woff</extension>
     <mime-type>application/x-font-woff</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```